# MySQL Error:10061

Tags: mysql

Apparently, I cannot connect to SQL server using the mysql.exe

I logged in as the root user and typed the following

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> CONNECT TO 127.0.0.1:3306;
```

I receive the folling error.

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.01:3306' (2)

Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3306' (2)
```

However it connects justs fine using MySQL Workbench with the same parameters.

```
Host:127.0.0.1
Port:3306
User: root
pass:[empty]
```

I have the easyphp MySQL module installed. Could this be the reason?

**EDIT:** TYPO with 127.0.0.1 sorry

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-commands.html), the syntax of the `connect` command is:

> ```
> connect [db_name host_name]], \r [db_name host_name]]
> ```
>
> Reconnect to the server. The optional database name and host name arguments may be given to specify the default database or the host where the server is running. If omitted, the current values are used.

Therefore your command `CONNECT TO 127.0.0.1:3306` is attempting to connect to a database called `TO` on a host called `127.0.0.1:3306`.  The error message you receive in return unsurprisingly complains that the host does not exist.

However, it is more usual to specify the hostname and database on invoking `mysql` (whereupon one can also specify the port if one wishes - see [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html) for a full list of command line options):

```
mysql -u username -p -h <hostname> -P <port> db_name
```

Also note that if the hostname and port are not specified, [they default to localhost and 3309](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/connecting.html) - therefore in your case you can omit all of the above and just go with:

```
mysql -u username -p db_name
```

To do what you're currently doing (not specifying the database name on the command-line), you must call the [`USE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/use.html) command at the `mysql>` prompt to select a database after you've connected:

```
mysql -u username -p
mysql> USE db_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

127.0.01 is explicitly misspelled. 127.0.0.1 is correct

Answer (score 0):

127.0.01:3306 IS NOT 127.0.0.1:3306

You forgot the dot.